# Durability & air-tightness of PUR tube on barbed air port

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I'd like to connect a long tube to a pressure sensor with a barbed port to measure air pressure (ambient air pressure +-10kPa). The sensor's barbed port has outer diameter 3mm.

I'm choosing between using silicone rubber tube, or a PUR (polyurethane) tube. The silicone tube seems the right choice, because it seems more elastic and I have the impression this tube is used for connecting to barbed ports in e.g. washing machines. However, PUR tube is 10x cheaper and I'm tempted to use that one instead, but I'm I don't know if it will work long-term. Could PUR tube lose its elasticity and the connection lose its air-tightness over time? These PUR tubes are used in pneumatics with special fittings where they work well, but I don't know about barbed ports with no extra clamps or locks.

Comment: How long are you planning to use them for. I've used PUR tubes (with fittings), and after a year of use in a indoor environment there is not a hint of a problem. However, I am uncertain what would happen in the same time if you exposed them in UV radiation (e.g. outdoors).

Comment: You can use PUR, it is used in industry very commonly and is replacing PVC derivatives (some Tygon types) in a significant number of places, albeit not in leak-critical applications. I've been using it for low pressure measurement devices in indoor use for years without issue. As you note it is a good deal stiffer vs Silicone. You should adjust the interference of the fit to account for this. Removing it from a barb may get difficult, otherwise it should be fine. It may stiffen slightly over over 5+ years time scale, but that may be a thing with clear vs opaque formulations of PUR. Ask vendor.

Comment: I once used a syringe to purge a device. Unfortunately, the silicone tube began to swell (inflate), its swell got to the barb, and blew-off the fitting before I could stop. Made a mess. A visual I will never forget.